# Go to a URL in a loop [several times]

Tags: php, url, curl

I've got a new SMS service for my php app. To send a message you need to go to an URL with the number and message as parameters.

**This sms service sucks, is from an external company I know :(**

> *//example.com/sms/?c=**number**&m=**message***

With an array of data I made a foreach loop to send each message.

```
<?php
// Users array
$users[] = ['Jhon', 123456789]
$users[] = ['Peter', 223456789]
$users[] = ['Sam', 323456789]
$users[] = ['Carl', 423456789]

// The loop
foreach ($users as $thisUser) {
    // URL builded with the users data
    $thisNumber = $thisUser[1];
    $thisMessage = 'Hey,+your+name+is+' . $thisUser[0]
    $request = sprintf('http://example.com/sms/?c=%d&m=Hey+%s+', $thisNumber, $thisMessage);
}
?>
```

Now, ¿witch is the best way to go that URL in a loop [several times]? Header redirection doesn't work for me. Maybe cURL...

Comment: _Header redirection doesn't work for me_ --  why? You could always change your API to accept a variable number of messages.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I'm guessing because he wants to run the page without leaving the current page. In which case, JavaScript is the best solution.

Comment: @TerryHarvey possibly, but then why doesn't he just call the URLs from PHP (with `file_get_contents` or something more complex)? @DanyCaissy same difference.

Comment: I've no influence on the API, is from an external company

Comment: @TerryHarvey how would it be with Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think JavaScript is a good solution. From the sound of it, you want to call that remote url so you can send an SMS. You can either use CURL or `file_get_contents` and just ignore the results (unless you need the results).

Comment: I mean, cURL would allow me to request that page several times and give me each result?

Comment: Yes it would. cURL is pretty advanced and may be overkill, which is why I suggested `file_get_contents`. It depends on if you're using the return data, headers, etc..